# how to make some grid view items not clickable

Tags: android, gridview, clickable

I have 20 images in gridview.

I need code to set the gridview item unclikable based on the position.

My aim is to check whether first two images I click in the gridview are equal or not. If they are equal, I have to set those images notclickable. If they are not equal, I have to set those images clickable based on the position. I have the code for checking whether two images are equal or not.

But I don't know how to set images in the gridview not clickable based on position.
I have tried these, `gridView.getChildAt(position).setClickable(false);`

If I used the above code, the image at corresponding position in the grid is clickable and 
also `onItemClick()` method is excuting.

Comment: By writing code, really write some code and post it here then I could copy it experiment with it and give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : 
                yourgridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = pos;
        //set condition for specific position
         if(position==5){
       //do what ever you want;
                   }else{

          }
    }
      });
```

I hope this will help u or someone else

Answer (score -1):

just set focusable to false in your programm where you need it.

```
image.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: I have two similar images in gridview.I want to set not clickable based on the position